# Why do two infinite planes contribute to Electric Field but not two surfaces in co-axial cylinder

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance, gauss-law, conductors

I understand why the electric field between two infinite planes is $\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}{\vec{e_z}}$. Both planes contribute to the field - the upper positive charged plane "pushes" towards the negatively charged plane, and the negatively charged plane "pulls" from the positively charged.

However, for a cylindrical or spherical gaussian geometry, we only consider the inner surface to "pull" the electric field. I understand it is a consequence of Gauss's Law for the enclosed charge, but it doesn't make physical sense to me. Physically, why do both surfaces contribute in one case but not in another?

For example, we could fix a radius to the cylindrical geometry and then do so much zoom-in to the surface that the curvature would be ignored and it looked like a very large local (infinite) plane. But the expression wouldn't hold on that case.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe consider a simpler problem 1st: one surface. An infinite plane of charge has a field on both sides of $\frac 1 2 \rho/\epsilon_0$, but if that plane is really a close up of a giant spherical surface: the inside goes to zero and the outside field doubles.